# He walked to the mall for or in ten minutes

Tags: prepositions

> He painted the wall *for* an hour. He painted the wall *in* an hour.

In the sentences above, I think "for" and "in" are both correct. "For" means he spent an hour painting the wall; it doesn't tell whether he finished the job or not. "In" tells us he finished the job; it took him an hour to paint the wall.

However, in the following pair of sentences, I feel only the second is correct. I can't tell why the first is wrong.

> He walked to the mall *for* ten minutes. He walked to the mall *in* ten minutes.

So, *"he painted the wall"* can mean he finished it or he only did a part. *"He walked to the mall"*, however, seems to only mean he reached the mall.

Can you please explain the reason?

Answer (score 1):

The mall is an *indirect* object: the wall a *direct* one.

"He walked to the mall" tells us he **completed** the journey. You can't complete a journey for ten minutes. If you said, "He walked **towards** the mall", I would know he hadn't yet reached his destination. So you *could* say, "He walked **towards** the mall for ten minutes".

"He walked to the mall **in** ten minutes" is perfect. If the time is important we might say, "It took him ten minutes to walk to the mall."

Comment: Thank you very much!